# Calculating documents and data storage used IOS7

Tags: ios

I am trying to find the total size of the documents directory of my IOS app. I believe it is the value that I see in the Settings app under usage (documents and data, this value now is 40MB). By using this method:

```
-(int)sizeOfFolder:(NSString *)folderPath
{
NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:nil];
NSEnumerator *contentsEnumurator = [contents objectEnumerator];

NSString *file;
unsigned long long int folderSize = 0;

while (file = [contentsEnumurator nextObject]) {
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:nil];
    folderSize += [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize] intValue];
}

//This line will give you formatted size from bytes ....
//NSString *folderSizeStr = [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:folderSize countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile];

NSLog(@"size: %llu", folderSize);

return folderSize;
}
```

I get always the same value. This is the path I pass onto the method:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* rootPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
int space = [self sizeOfFolder:rootPath];
```

Comment: i didnt get your question,`I get always the same value.` ??

Comment: I mean for size I get a constant value of 890 bytes, even if I save other files

Comment: put break point and check your `contents` array?

Comment: Did you get something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be careful with file types. You should use `long long` to be able to calculate the total size:

```
unsigned long long folderSize = 0; // remove int here
// ...
folderSize += [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize] longLongValue]; // note longLongValue
```

Next you should skip directories to get more accurate results

```
if (![fileAttirbutes[NSFileType] equalsToString:NSFileTypeDirectory]) {
    folderSize += ...
}
```

I would recommend you to look at another directory enumeration approach. Using `- (NSDirectoryEnumerator *)enumeratorAtURL:(NSURL *)url includingPropertiesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions)mask errorHandler:(BOOL (^)(NSURL *url, NSError *error))handler` will allow you to perform deeper directory enumeration and list all directory contents recursively

```
unsigned long long count = 0;
NSNumber *value = nil;

for (NSURL *url in [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLFileSizeKey] options:0 errorHandler:NULL]) {
    if ([url getResourceValue:&value forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:outError]) {
        count += [value longLongValue];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

return @(count);
```

Comment: In the case I wanted to use - (NSDirectoryEnumerator *)enumeratorAtURL:(NSURL *)url includingPropertiesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions)mask errorHandler:(BOOL (^)(NSURL *url, NSError *error))handler how would the method become? Sorry but I have never used it...

Comment: Actually it allows you to handle enumeration error in early stages and stop the enumeration by returning NO: `BOOL ^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {if (!url) {NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]); return NO;} else return YES;}`

Comment: @Alessandro Sorry for some copy paste problems in example, got the code from NSFileManager category :-)

Answer (score 0):

NSFileManager has no capabilities of returning the size of a folder(a folder + contents). Found this on Internet.

> ```
> - (unsigned long long) fastFolderSizeAtFSRef:(FSRef*)theFileRef {
> FSIterator    thisDirEnum = NULL;
> unsigned long long totalSize = 0;
>
> // Iterate the directory contents, recursing as necessary
> if (FSOpenIterator(theFileRef, kFSIterateFlat, &thisDirEnum) == noErr)
> {
>     const ItemCount kMaxEntriesPerFetch = 256;
>     ItemCount actualFetched;
>     FSRef    fetchedRefs[kMaxEntriesPerFetch];
>     FSCatalogInfo fetchedInfos[kMaxEntriesPerFetch];
>
>     // DCJ Note right now this is only fetching data fork sizes... if we decide to include
>     // resource forks we will have to add kFSCatInfoRsrcSizes
>
>     OSErr fsErr = FSGetCatalogInfoBulk(thisDirEnum, kMaxEntriesPerFetch, &actualFetched,
>                                     NULL, kFSCatInfoDataSizes | kFSCatInfoNodeFlags, fetchedInfos,
>                                     fetchedRefs, NULL, NULL);
>     while ((fsErr == noErr) || (fsErr == errFSNoMoreItems))
>     {
>         ItemCount thisIndex;
>         for (thisIndex = 0; thisIndex < actualFetched; thisIndex++)
>            {
>             // Recurse if it's a folder
>            if (fetchedInfos[thisIndex].nodeFlags & kFSNodeIsDirectoryMask)
>             {
>                 totalSize += [self fastFolderSizeAtFSRef:&fetchedRefs[thisIndex]];
>             }
>             else
>             {
>
>               totalSize += fetchedInfos [thisIndex].dataLogicalSize;
>             }
>         }
>
>         if (fsErr == errFSNoMoreItems)
>         {
>             break;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             // get more items
>             fsErr = FSGetCatalogInfoBulk(thisDirEnum, kMaxEntriesPerFetch, &actualFetched,
>                                     NULL, kFSCatInfoDataSizes | kFSCatInfoNodeFlags, fetchedInfos,
>                                     fetchedRefs, NULL, NULL);
>         }
>     }
>     FSCloseIterator(thisDirEnum);
> }
> return totalSize; }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Hassana, has this code been tested? It contains more than 10 red errors...